# Thinkpad USB keyboard trackpoint to scroll in Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: thinkpad, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, trackpoint

How one would configure external thinkpad USB keyboard with trackpoint to scroll in Visual Studio 2013/2015?

Note: just noticed that the scroll works only when the VS window is **inactive**.
Edit: Using a Windows 10 machine.